# Is 'was' or is 'were' correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, syntactic-analysis

In this particular sentence, is it correct to use "was", or is it correct to use "were":

"All I wore **was** jeans."

or

"All I wore **were** jeans."

Comment: You'll be glad to know that the answer is yes, it is.

Comment: @tchrist hahahah nice catch

Comment: "was" -- Compare "All is quiet"; "All I want for Christmas is my two front teeth."

Comment: "Jeans" is even mushier than "pants" when it comes to deciding if it's singular or plural.  No doubt there are "authorities" who will tell you that one or the other is the only "correct" way, but "jeans" is really sensitive to context, register, social biases, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks So this jeans looks good on you in your language?

Comment: @tchrist - No, jeans always look mushy on me.

Comment: @HotLicks The real issue, as Greg Lee has pointed out, is that in English even a linking verb like *be* must agree only with its subject, not with its complement. The subject is  *”All that I wore“*, which is singular no matter what follows the verb because here *All* means *the only thing*.  In contrast, *“All (the folks) that volunteered are here now”* shows a plural possibility.